# connection timeout to codebuild project invoked by lambda function in python

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-codebuild

I have a simple lambda function in python that invokes the codebuild project:

import json, boto3, time

```
def handler(event, context):
    print(event)
    # execute the testsuite (by triggering a codebuild project which executes the soapui TestSuite)
    codebuild = boto3.client('codebuild')
    print ("hi")
    responseStart = codebuild.start_build(projectName="SpSoapUITest")
    print (responseStart['build']['id'])
    print (responseStart)
    # wait 180 seconds to read the result from codeBuild job
    time.sleep(180)
    
    # parse the result
    response = codebuild.batch_get_builds(
        ids=[ str(responseStart['build']['id']) ]
    )
    if response['builds'][0]['buildStatus'] == 'SUCCEEDED':
        status = "Succeeded"
    else:
        status = "Failed"
    
    # send result to event
    try:
        codedeploy = boto3.client('codedeploy')
        codedeploy.put_lifecycle_event_hook_execution_status(
            deploymentId=event["DeploymentId"],
            lifecycleEventHookExecutionId=event["LifecycleEventHookExecutionId"],
            status=status
        )
        return True
    except codedeploy.exceptions.ClientError as e:
        print("Unexpected error: %s" % e)
        return False
```

but it is timing out after printing hi saying the connection timeout

```
[ERROR] ConnectTimeoutError: Connect timeout on endpoint URL: "https://codebuild.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/spLambda.py", line 8, in handler
    responseStart = codebuild.start_build(projectName="mihir-usagemonitor-dev-SpSoapUITest")
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 357, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 662, in _make_api_call
    http, parsed_response = self._make_request(
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 682, in _make_request
    return self._endpoint.make_request(operation_model, request_dict)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/endpoint.py", line 102, in make_request
    return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/endpoint.py", line 136, in _send_request
    while self._needs_retry(attempts, operation_model, request_dict,
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/endpoint.py", line 253, in _needs_retry
    responses = self._event_emitter.emit(
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/hooks.py", line 356, in emit
    return self._emitter.emit(aliased_event_name, **kwargs)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/hooks.py", line 228, in emit
    return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/hooks.py", line 211, in _emit
    response = handler(**kwargs)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 183, in __call__
    if self._checker(attempts, response, caught_exception):
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 250, in __call__
    should_retry = self._should_retry(attempt_number, response,
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 277, in _should_retry
    return self._checker(attempt_number, response, caught_exception)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 316, in __call__
    checker_response = checker(attempt_number, response,
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 222, in __call__
    return self._check_caught_exception(
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 359, in _check_caught_exception
    raise caught_exception
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/endpoint.py", line 200, in _do_get_response
    http_response = self._send(request)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/endpoint.py", line 269, in _send
    return self.http_session.send(request)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/httpsession.py", line 287, in send
    raise ConnectTimeoutError(endpoint_url=request.url, error=e)
END RequestId: 8e5bbd96-7373-4f5e-9f8d-adea8dc30211
REPORT RequestId: 8e5bbd96-7373-4f5e-9f8d-adea8dc30211  Duration: 305498.32 ms  Billed Duration: 305499 ms  Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 73 MB  Init Duration: 323.83 ms
```

I have attached following policies to lambda role:

1. AWSCodeBuildDeveloperAccess
2. AWSCodeDeployFullAccess
3. AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess
4. AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole

What could be the reason for timout ?

Answer (score 2):

Lambda function associated with a VPC has **no internet access**, unless VPC allows it. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html#vpc-internet):

> When you connect a function to a VPC in your account, the function **can't access the internet** unless your VPC provides access.

Subsequently, your function **can't connect** to the public endpoints of the CodeBuild (CB) service. To rectify this, there are **two options**:

- place your function in **private subnet** (public will not work), setup **NAT** gateway in a public subnet and configure route tables so that your function can access internet using NAT. The process is explained [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/).
- setup [VPC endpoint for CB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/use-vpc-endpoints-with-codebuild.html). This will allow your function to **privately** access CB service without the need for internet access.

Comment: the problem is with lambda funtion or the codebuild project? Codebuild project is not associated with the VPC

Comment: @MiGo Its not a problem. Its rather a design choice. Maybe you don't need to place lambda in VPC at all? Is it requirement?